# PDO Binding Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting the following SQL error for the given code.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that coresponds
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at
>   line 1

The code:

```
$set_query = "";

foreach ($passed_columns as $c)
{
    $set_query .= $c . " = " . ':' . $c . ',';
}

$p = strlen($set_query);
$set_query[$p-1] = "";

$SQL = 'UPDATE users SET ' . $set_query . ' WHERE user_id IN (' . implode(",", $_POST['user_id']) . ')';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($SQL);

foreach($_POST['cols'] as $key => $val)
{
    $stmt->bindValue(':' . $key, $val);
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo()));
}
```

$_POST['cols'] contains a key value array of (column_name => new column value).
$passed_columns just contains an array of column names that match the keys in $_POST['cols']

I believe the issue has to do with the way the values are bound.  If I echo the $SQL variable, the output is valid SQL(with the values I'm testing).

But oddly enough, if I manually set $SQL to the valid SQL it just output ("UPDATE users SET role = :role WHERE user_id IN (100)"), the script works.

Comment: It is a MySQL error, prior to binding.  `echo $SQL` to see what the constructed statement looks like. It's going to have something strange in it causing that ambiguous error message.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out your query? What does it look like?

Comment: The echoed query is valid SQL (after it is constructed) and if I copy the query into Workbench/execute it manually, it works. It looks like this : "UPDATE users SET role=:role WHERE user_id IN (100)"

Comment: It _isn't_ valid SQL though, which is why it reports a SQL syntax error. Please post it exactly as PHP constructs it.

Comment: @syl - Also, which line generates the error? The prepare, the bind, or the execute?

Comment: The exact SQL, copy and pasted here: "UPDATE users SET role = :role WHERE user_id IN (1638)" and the execute is what generates the error.

Comment: @syl - you're generating the parameters for the SQL in a different way to how you're then passing them in - is that an issue? The SQL is generated in a loop `foreach ($passed_columns as $c)`; while the parameters are bound in a loop `foreach($_POST['cols'] as $key => $val)` - are you maybe binding different columns? How is `$passed_columns` generated?

Comment: @andrewsi Even if I replaced the $passed_columns (which is just the array_keys of $_POST['cols']) with $_POST['cols'] as $key=> val, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @syl - huh. The only thing I can think of is to check the inputs to see if there are unexpected characters being passed in - something that wouldn't show up in HTML output, but would in plain text. I guess for debugging you could strip out all non-alphanumerics to see if the issue goes away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feedback:

- Using `"string" . $var` gets really unreadable quickly.  PHP can embed variables directly in strings: `"string $var"` and if you need to do array expressions you can use curly braces like `"string {$arr['key']}"`.
- I recommend to delimit the column names with back-ticks.
- Chopping the last comma off the set-list is clumsy.  Better to build the set-list as an array and implode using comma.
- Your IN list is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Map the user_id values with (int) to remove possible malicious content.  If the user_id values aren't integers, then use query parameters (but don't mix `?` positional parameters with named parameters in a single statement -- it confuses PDO).
- bind_param() is unnecessary.  Just pass the parameter values to execute().  In modern versions of PHP, the leading colon in key values is unnecessary, which makes it simpler to pass the parameters directly from a key/value array.
- It's not clear from your example if $passed_columns is something taken from user input, or if it's hard-coded in your app.  Be careful of introducing SQL injection this way.  I'll assume $passed_columns contains only values you control.
- prepare() returns `false` on error, so you should always check its return value and respond to the error appropriately.
- [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) actually prints to output, instead of returning a string, unless you pass the optional second argument true.
- It's a surprise to most PHP developers, but double-quoted strings are actually slightly faster than single-quoted strings.  The difference is very small regardless, but double-quoted strings allow you to put variables directly in the string, so why not?

Here's how I would write the code:

```
$set_terms = array();
foreach ($passed_columns as $c)
{
    $set_terms[] = "`$c` = :$c";
}
$set_clause = implode(",", $set_terms);

$user_id_list = implode(",", array_map(function($id) { return (int) $id; },
  $_POST["user_id"]);

$SQL = "UPDATE users SET {$set_clause} WHERE user_id IN ({$user_id_list})";

if (!($stmt = $dbh->prepare($SQL)) {
    die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));
}

if (!$stmt->execute($_POST["cols"])) {
    die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));
}
```

PS: Just using die() if you get an error might not be the best thing to do.  A professional web interface would log the error for developers, and then present a nicer screen to the user.

Comment: This works, and is way better than the way I wrote it.  I just wish I knew why my way didn't work.

Comment: Yeah it's a mystery.  You could enable the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html), which logs failed queries, and see what SQL is actually reaching the MySQL server when it thinks there is an error.  But sometimes I do run into code that mysteriously fails, and when I rewrite it, something is fixed in the process.  It'd be nice to know what was the original problem, but otherwise take the win and move on.  :-)